# socket.accept() returns invalid argument when run inside a class

Tags: python, sockets

This is my first stab at a custom game/interface in python. I have started with the communication needed for connecting to the game server from the controller. I want to make the communication a object so that I can call it from within the game. The issue I am running into is that when I call server.serverRun() I get an exception OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied. Now when outside of the object this all runs fine. I am not sure what I am missing.

'''

```
#game.py
import math,random,sys,time,os
import comm

serverStatus = False

while True:
    server = comm.server()
    if serverStatus == False:
        serverStatus = server.serverStart("127.0.0.1",1234)
    else:
        server.serverRun()



#comm.py
import os,socket,pickle,select

class server():

    HeaderLength = 10
    GameStatus = {"state": 0, "Sound" : 0}

    def __init__(self):
        self.clients = {}
        self.clientSocket = ""
        self.clientAddress = ("",0)
        # Create a socket
        # socket.AF_INET - address family, IPv4, some other possible are AF_INET6, AF_BLUETOOTH, AF_UNIX
        # socket.SOCK_STREAM - TCP, conection-based, socket.SOCK_DGRAM - UDP, connectionless, datagrams, socket.SOCK_RAW - raw IP packets
        self.serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        # SO_ - socket option
        # SOL_ - socket option level
        # Sets REUSEADDR (as a socket option) to 1 on socket
        self.serverSocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

    def serverStart(self,IP,PORT):
        try:

            # Bind, so server informs operating system that it's going to use given IP and port
            # For a server using 0.0.0.0 means to listen on all available interfaces, useful to connect locally to 127.0.0.1 and remotely to LAN interface IP
            self.serverSocket.bind((IP, PORT))

            # This makes server listen to new connections
            self.serverSocket.listen(5)
            print (f"IP Adddress: {IP}")
            print (f"Port #: {PORT}")
            return True

        except:
            print ("Connection Error")
            return False

    def serverRun(self):
        self.clientSocket, self.clientAddress = self.serverSocket.accept()
        print(f"Address {self.clientAddress}")
```

'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while True:
    server = comm.server()
    if serverStatus == False:
        serverStatus = server.serverStart("127.0.0.1",1234)
    else:
        server.serverRun()
```

You create a new socket using `server = comm.server()` for each iteration of the loop.
But you only bind+listen on the server socket in the first iteration. 
This means that in the second iteration you have a fresh socket which is not bound and not ready to listen but you call accept on it.

I.e. first iteration:

```
server = comm.server()    # creates new socket for listener
# calls bind + listen
serverStatus = server.serverStart("127.0.0.1",1234)
```

Second iteration

```
server = comm.server()       # creates new socket for listener
# calls accept on this new socket without calling bind+listen before -> Error
server.serverRun()
```

Instead of creating this strange while-loop you should just do the following:

```
server = comm.server()                  # creates socket - only once
server.serverStart("127.0.0.1",1234)    # calls bind+listen - only once too
while True:
    server.serverRun()                  # calls accept - for every new connection
```

Comment: Thank you. I completely missed that I was declaring the com.server in the loop. Moved it out before the loop and it works correctly. The reason for the If else is to tell me that the server is listening. I was thinking it may be needed for error handling.